# Bootstrap not showing full height column

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Pardon if this is too much of a newbie question, or just not the right type of question. I am in the beginning phase of learning how to program and one of my first tasks is getting my annotation editor to work.

I use bootstrap to create columns; namely, the column on the right (1/12th of sceen) to contain the different colors, and the other 11/12th column to contain the entire annotation editor(the pictures, etc). This all works well, except for the fact that my right column does not work or show up.

I think I am pretty sure that I closed the column of the first 11 portions, but trying to create another div with 1 column simply doesn't work; thus, I cannot put anything in it and can't put my colors in there.

The HTML syntax looks like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="2048_MMA/style/bootstrap.min.css" type ="text/css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/clouds.css" type="text/css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/background.css" type="text/css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/dropdownmenu.css"/>
<style>
body{
background: #c9dbe9;
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #c9dbe9 0%, #fff 100%);
background: -linear-gradient(top, #c9dbe9 0%, #fff 100%);
background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #c9dbe9 0%, #fff 100%);
padding-bottom: 500px;
}
iframe {
height: 670px;
width: 1200px;
margin-left:25%;
}
</style>
</head>

<body onload="init()">
    <nav class="nav">
        <ul>
            <li>
                <a href="portfolio_index.html">Home</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#">Applications</a>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="mediaviewer.html">Mediaviewer</a></li>
                    <li><a href="annotation editor.html">Annotation editor</a></li>
                    <li><a href="2048_MMA/portfolio_2048_water.html">2048</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#">Essays</a>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">Essay Lea</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Essay Jonathan</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Essay Jelmer</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </nav>

    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-11">
                <script type="text/javascript">
                    var canvas, ctx, flag = false,
                            prevX = 0,
                            currX = 0,
                            prevY = 0,
                            currY = 0,
                            dot_flag = false;

                    var x = "black",
                            y = 2;

                    function init() {
                        canvas = document.getElementById('can');
                        ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
                        w = canvas.width;
                        h = canvas.height;

                        canvas.addEventListener("mousemove", function(e) {
                            findxy('move', e)
                        }, false);
                        canvas.addEventListener("mousedown", function(e) {
                            findxy('down', e)
                        }, false);
                        canvas.addEventListener("mouseup", function(e) {
                            findxy('up', e)
                        }, false);
                        canvas.addEventListener("mouseout", function(e) {
                            findxy('out', e)
                        }, false);
                    }

                    function color(obj) {
                        switch (obj.id) {
                            case "green":
                                x = "green";
                                break;
                            case "blue":
                                x = "blue";
                                break;
                            case "red":
                                x = "red";
                                break;
                            case "yellow":
                                x = "yellow";
                                break;
                            case "orange":
                                x = "orange";
                                break;
                            case "black":
                                x = "black";
                                break;
                            case "purple":
                                x = "purple";
                                break;
                            case "grey":
                                x = "grey";
                                break;
                        }
                        if (x == "white")
                            y = 14;
                        else
                            y = 2;

                    }

                    function draw() {
                        ctx.beginPath();
                        ctx.moveTo(prevX, prevY);
                        ctx.lineTo(currX, currY);
                        ctx.strokeStyle = x;
                        ctx.lineWidth = y;
                        ctx.stroke();
                        ctx.closePath();
                    }

                    function erase() {
                        var m = confirm("Verwijder je kunstwerk?");
                        if (m) {
                            ctx.clearRect(0, 0, w, h);
                            document.getElementById("canvasimg").style.display = "none";
                        }
                    }
                    function findxy(res, e) {
                        if (res == 'down') {
                            prevX = currX;
                            prevY = currY;
                            currX = e.clientX - canvas.offsetLeft;
                            currY = e.clientY - canvas.offsetTop;

                            flag = true;
                            dot_flag = true;
                            if (dot_flag) {
                                ctx.beginPath();
                                ctx.fillStyle = x;
                                ctx.fillRect(currX, currY, 2, 2);
                                ctx.closePath();
                                dot_flag = false;
                            }
                        }
                        if (res == 'up' || res == "out") {
                            flag = false;
                        }
                        if (res == 'move') {
                            if (flag) {
                                prevX = currX;
                                prevY = currY;
                                currX = e.clientX - canvas.offsetLeft;
                                currY = e.clientY - canvas.offsetTop;
                                draw();
                            }
                        }
                    }
                </script>
                <iframe src="mediaviewer2.html"></iframe>
                <canvas id="can" width="1080%" height="610%" style="position:absolute;top:0.5%;left:29%;border:5px solid;"></canvas>
                <img id="canvasimg" style="position:absolute;top:30%;left:54%;">
                <input type="button" value="Reset" id="clr" size="23" onclick="erase()" style="position:absolute;top:15%;left:55%;height:40px;width:50px;">
            </div> <!--end column--->

            <div class="col-md-1">
                <div style="position:absolute;top:%;left:50%;">Kies een kleurtje!</div>
                <div style="position:absolute;top:15%;left:50%;width:15px;height:15px;background:green;" id="green" onclick="color(this)"></div>
                <div style="position:absolute;top:15%;left:51%;width:15px;height:15px;background:blue;" id="blue" onclick="color(this)"></div>
                <div style="position:absolute;top:15%;left:52%;width:15px;height:15px;background:red;" id="red" onclick="color(this)"></div>
                <div style="position:absolute;top:20%;left:50%;width:15px;height:15px;background:yellow;" id="yellow" onclick="color(this)"></div>
                <div style="position:absolute;top:20%;left:51%;width:15px;height:15px;background:orange;" id="orange" onclick="color(this)"></div>
                <div style="position:absolute;top:20%;left:52%;width:15px;height:15px;background:black;" id="black" onclick="color(this)"></div>
                <div style="position:absolute;top:20%;left:53%;width:15px;height:15px;background:purple;" id="purple" onclick="color(this)"></div>
                <div style="position:absolute;top:15%;left:53%;width:15px;height:15px;background:grey;" id="grey" onclick="color(this)"></div>
            </div>


            <div id="clouds">
                <div class="cloud x1"></div>
                <div class="cloud x2"></div>
                <div class="cloud x3"></div>
                <div class="cloud x4"></div>
                <div class="cloud x5"></div>
                <div class="cloud x6"></div>
                <div class="cloud x7"></div>
                <div class="cloud x8"></div>
                <div class="cloud x9"></div>
                <div class="cloud x10"></div>
                <div class="cloud x11"></div>
            </div> <!--end clouds-->
        </div><!--end row-->    
    </div><!--end container-->
</body>
```

This picture depicts what I mean. Can you spot any mistakes in the HTML markup itself?
https://i.stack.imgur.com/MmtS0.jpg

Comment: Your HTML is not valid. Width attributes over 100% are strange, also input should not have a size attribute. You should put your JS code into a separate file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a couple of potential issues that I see.

One is that your iframe has a width of 1200px and a height of 670px.  That's not responsive.  So, on smaller viewports, you wouldn't be able to see the entire contents and it will break out of the columns.  Happily, Bootstrap offers some nice features to make your iframe responsive.  To do this, you'd use the Bootstrap [Responsive Embed](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#responsive-embed) classes.  This creates a container with an intrinsic ratio of either 4:3 or 16:9.  Basically that means that the iframe scales proportional to one of those two ratios and keeps you from having to specify fixed values.  The markup that is applied looks like this:

```
<div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9">
  <iframe class="embed-responsive-item" src="…"></iframe>
</div>
```

This also now allows you to set your width and height on the canvas element to 100% and use top/left/bottom/right properties set to 0 so that it will fill the same space as the iframe regardless of the size of the viewport.

The second issue is that you have set all of the content in your col-md-1 div to be positioned absolutely, and you are using % for the top and left values.  This isn't going to work, because a div with no content has a height of 0.  Therefore, unless you give the col-md-1 a fixed height value, you'll only be positioning the content against 0 (and 50% of 0 is still 0).  Providing a fixed height to the column is of course an option, but again it's not terribly responsive.  The better option here would be to use fixed values for your top and left properties.  After all, you are positioning elements that have a fixed size, so there's no problem with them overlapping provided that you give each at least 15px of room.

The best option by far though, would be to not use absolute positioning for those elements, and simply let your elements be in the document flow.  You can even use a css trick similar to the one used in Bootstrap's responsive embeds to create an element that has proportional height and width, yet scales with the overall design.  You can see in the demo that no matter what size the viewport is, the color blocks scale with it.

## [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/jme11/Lex3co5y/)

I've also adapted the demo to use the conventional built in Bootstrap features for buttons, navigation and dropdowns.  Learning to use what the framework offers will definitely help save you time and effort in development, testing and maintenance.

Comment: Thank you very much :), I am going to try to fix the issue built on your feedback. Made my day